gfortran if statement issue with array and logical scalar
I have the following partial code that gives me an issue,
module test_module
implicit none
contains

subroutine test(x, y)

! Input parameters:
real(8), intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
real(8) :: ay, by, sigmay(size(x))


ay = 0.34
by = 0.82
sigmay = ay * abs(x)**by * (x > 0.0)

end subroutine test
end module test_module

I am getting error message in compilation due to real value operation on logical value.  My fix attempt is as follows,
if (all(x(:)>(0.0:0.0)) then 
sigmay = ay * abs(x)**by *x
else
sigmay = 0.0
end if

After the fix, I am getting another error which I have no clue what causing it.  Any ideas where I am doing wrong?
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

it is pointing at zero after period.  The first zeros in brackets.

Looks like you want to use a WHERE statement.  WHERE (X > 0) SIGMAY = AY * ABS(X)**BY * x

Your solution works.

Be aware that your numeric literals are the default (double) precision and you assign them into kind 8 variables. Kind 8 is not portable, but is likely double precision for you.  I strongly recommend to use some indentation.
